# Everything is back to zero when I hover over my username

Tags: support, reputation

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

This seems to be happening in all sites, on code review (where I got some rep recently) the latest is showing up (This are the first point I made on Code review just in case).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I've changed the tag from bug to support since it seems to be by design.

Comment: It may be by design, but the design is bad in my opinion. It's hard to find the reputation changes of the last couple of hours. (Click on the "reputation" row header and then click on "by time" or "by post" tab). To make things worse the user interface does not even hint that "week" starts on Sunday (!) and "month" is calendar based instead of going back the amount of time from now.

Comment: Even though this is by design, it's somewhat of a bad design in my opinion. I saw the same thing today and immediately remembered that it's the 1st of May, but I fail to see how calender months could be relevant to what I'd expect to see in the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the beginning of both a new week (Sunday) and a new month (May). These are absolute periods, not relative ones.

Comment: Ohh! Did not now that! So by design then, Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed (I'm -particularly- slow today). That this was quite obvious, it actually says `month` and the month is wel... gone.